# After Successful completion of deployment status in Openshift through Eclipse, 404 error page is shown

Tags: spring, http-status-code-404, openshift

After Successful completion of deployment status of my Java EE application (Spring ) in Openshift through Eclipse, 404 error page is shown on launching "http://closerbyapp-closerbyonline.rhcloud.com/closerbyapp" url.

Any help to Sort out this problem is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Did you actually deploy an application at the closerbyapp context? the root context (/) of your application is working and showing the default index.html page that comes with the java cartridges.  You should double-check how/where you put your code, and that you added it to git, and what url it should show up at.  Maybe provide some of the code you used or steps that you took to deploy the code so we can help troubleshoot it? Along with any logs for your application that might be helpful.